# IntelliJ IDEA: Could not find or load main class C:\Program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a problem with building my project in `IntelliJ IDEA`. I'm new to Java and this IDE, so there might be some stupid things I've made wrong. Anyway I'm sure the project is written correctly. This is the message I get after clicking "`Build Project`" button:

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
C:\Users\artartart\.IdeaIC2017.2\config\jdks\jbsdk8u112b287.2_windows_x64\jre\bin\java -Xmx4096m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=3244537063909990413 C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\plugins\android\lib\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar -Dfile.encoding=windows-1250 -Djps.file.types.component.name=CommunityFileTypes -Duser.language=pl -Duser.country=PL -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2017.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\artartart\.IdeaIC2017.2\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\artartart\.IdeaIC2017.2\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/artartart/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Users/artartart/.IdeaIC2017.2/config/jdks/jbsdk8u112b287.2_windows_x64 -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_112-release -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/artartart/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/compile-server/lux_f88e3d21/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.experimental=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\ARTART~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-2207181666383577824-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Users/artartart/.IdeaIC2017.2/config/jdks/jbsdk8u112b287.2_windows_x64/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/ecj-4.6.2.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/lz4-java-1.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/netty-all-4.1.10.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/httpcore-4.4.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/asm-all.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/openapi.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/httpclient-4.5.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/guava-21.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/lib/guava-21.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/repository.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/android-extensions-ide.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/Kotlin/lib/android-extensions-compiler.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 65171 0e58ca16-00f9-4b57-8012-4ea0e9b5be70 C:/Users/artartart/.IdeaIC2017.2/system/compile-server
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Program
```

I can't find any solution to fix this.
I'm running `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4 x64`, `JDK: 1.8 x64` and the project is based on `JDK 1.6`

I've been searching the solution for last couple of hours and nothing helped. I'm not sure if I provided enough information. If not - let me know :)

Thanks!

Comment: I would blame (one of the) argument(s), whitespaces (as in "Program Files") must be escaped. Actually, the "" should do the trick though. But if you look at the error, it states "there is no main class in C:\Program", what is probably correct ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to directory names with spaces not being surrounded with quotes in the command.

Whatever's adding

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\plugins\android\lib\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
```

to your build command is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the command line breaks after the first blank ' '. So try to wrap all parameters which contain a blank into double quotes:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\plugins\android\lib\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar"
```